# How to check that there is no character after a string when using 'in' in python

Tags: python, string, countries

```
locations=['london, uk','kiev, ukraine']

for i in range(len(locations)):
    if ', uk' in locations[i]:
        print(locations[i])
```

right now this prints both values in the list, how can I make it only print the first one?

Comment: `locations[i].endswith(', uk')`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `str.endswith`.

```
>>> locations=['london, uk','kiev, ukraine']
>>>   
>>> for loc in locations:
...     if loc.endswith(', uk'):
...         print(loc)
... 
london, uk
```

Note how you can iterate over `locations` directly without having to refer to list indices.

I encourage you to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o) for learning idiomatic iteration in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Or a quick list comprehension:

```
[i for i in locations if i.endswith('uk')]
```

If you have multiple strings, you will get a list of all the strings that ends with `'uk'`.

Answer (score 0):

To give more options using `regex`. `endswith` is also an option just to check the string with ends with substring`', uk'`.

```
import re
locations=['london, uk','kiev, ukraine']

for i in range(len(locations)):
    if re.search(', uk$',locations[i]):
        print(locations[i])
```

Or list comprehension

```
[i for i in locations if re.search(', uk$',i)]
```